# How to divide Spark Dataframe among several nodes that each one has unique key

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I am newbie in `Spark Dataframe`. I have a large Dataframe with one key column in Spark cluster with 4 nodes. For each key, I have several records in the Dataframe; so,I want to have records with the same key in each node as long as the memory has capacity. If memory of node is full, remain data are moved to another node.

Would you please guide me how to do that?

I have studied about writing Spark custom partition which is just used on `pair RDD` with `partionBy`. It writes the data for every unique combination in a different files. In fact,I don't want to use partitionBy because it writes its results in different files.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to repartition your dataset if you don't want to write it to files in a specific way?

Comment: Dear @krezno thank you for your feedback.In fact, I already have a table in database, after reading the table and save it to Spark Dataframe, I must process each key of Dataframe and save it to database.

Comment: I suppose you are performing some sort of aggregation on each key? The groupBy Operator automatically repartitions your data.

Comment: @krezno, yes I have to perform some aggregation on data. ```groupby``` repartitions data, but it has high cost.

Comment: Do you know if your data is skewed (i.e. there are keys with much more records than others)?

Comment: @krezno,I have keys with much more records that they cannot be fitted into RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is skewed and therefore isn't partitioned properly.

One simple way to solve this is salting your data as seen in [this example](https://medium.com/appsflyer/salting-your-spark-to-scale-e6f1c87dd18). You add a random number to your key, perform the aggregation to decrease the number of records in your RDD, then perform the aggregation again on less data. That way your initial large data-set is partitioned evenly across your nodes.